# Strange output of NIntegrate when constraining the precision with $Pre

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation

One can constrain the precision of `NIntegrate` by setting `PrecisionGoal`:

```
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] // FullForm
(*==> 1.1045695042415091`*)

NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 2] // FullForm
(*==> 1.1052223748431014`*)
```

Since I have a lot of NIntegrate functions in my work,
I want to set globally the `PrecisionGoal` to save the labor.
Here is what I did:

```
$Pre = Function[{expr}, 
   expr /. NIntegrate -> (NIntegrate[##, PrecisionGoal -> 2] &), 
   HoldAll];
```

However, `Trace` shows that the above setting does not work as expected:

```
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] // Trace
```

> {**(NIntegrate[##1,PrecisionGoal->2]&)[1/Sqrt[x+y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]**,{{{Sqrt[x+y],Sqrt[x+y]},1/Sqrt[x+y],1/Sqrt[x+y]},1/Sqrt[x+y],1/Sqrt[x+y]},{{x,y}=.,{x=.,y=.},{x=.,Null},{y=.,Null},{Null,Null}},{x=.,Null},{x=.,Null},{y=.,Null},{{x,y}=.,{x=.,y=.},{x=.,Null},{y=.,Null},{Null,Null}},{Message[General::munfl,0.5 4.03260792527738429574651585273435131279232623753622748828066970190*10^-330],Null},{Message[**General::munfl**,0.5 4.03260792527738429574651585273435131279232623753622748828066970190*10^-330],Null},{Message[General::munfl,0.5 4.03260792527738429574651585273435131279232623753622748828066970190*10^-330],{Message[General::stop,General::munfl],{General::stop,Further output of `1` will be suppressed during this calculation.},Null},Null},{Message[General::munfl,0.03125 2.52037995329836518484157240795896957049520389846014218017541856369*10^-331],Null},{Message[General::munfl,0.03125 2.52037995329836518484157240795896957049520389846014218017541856369*10^-331],Null},..., **1.10457**}

One can see that the numerical integration is still carried out with **high** precision,
even though the first line in trace didn't ask for this.
This claim can be verified by

```
$Pre=.
(NIntegrate[##1, PrecisionGoal -> 2] &)[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
(*==> 1.10522*)
```

Apart from this, there are many `General::munfl` warnings.

My question is how to understand the above behaviors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another story of evaluation order. You've only set one `HoldAll` for the pure function in `$Pre`, that's not enough. The function `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) doesn't have `HoldAll` attribute, either! Once the `NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` is passed to `/.`, it'll immediately be evaluated, before the replacement happens. You need to stop this in some way, one possible solution is to use `Unevaluated`:

```
$Pre =.

$Pre = Function[{expr}, 
   Unevaluated@expr /. NIntegrate -> (NIntegrate[##, PrecisionGoal -> 2] &), 
   HoldAll];

NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
(* 1.10522 *)
```

"OK, then why do I see the strange output with `Trace`?" That's because all of the output of `Trace` is wrapped by `HoldForm`…:

```
$Pre =.
Trace[NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]] // InputForm
```

[image]

So what really happens here is:

1. The line `NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] // Trace` evaluates before the replacement happens.
2. The replacement happens on the output of `Trace[…]`.

i.e. something amount to the following:

```
$Pre =.
Trace[NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]];
% /. NIntegrate -> (NIntegrate[##, PrecisionGoal -> 2] &)
```

Comment: Wooo, thank you so much! I didn't realize that in this particular case, the output of `Trace` could be _distorted_ by the sneaky replacement due to `HoldForm` and `ReplaceAll`.